# Does systemd require a password in the unit file in order to run gunicorn under a specific user?

Tags: linux, systemd, gunicorn

I want to run gunicorn as a service on a production server and have looked at many examples of the systemd unit file which are similar to this

```
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve application
After=network.target

[Service]
User=backend
Group=backend
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/app
Environment="PATH=/path/to/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/path/to/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:5003 web_dynamic.2-hbnb:app
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=5
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But I notice they don't specify a password for the user.

First of all, does systemd require a password in order to run gunicorn as a service?
If it does not, how does it run the service as that user?

Should I still create a password for the user?

Comment: `systemd` runs as a `root` and can switch to any user ID. It doesn't need a password for that.

Comment: A good practice is to create a separate user for a service with a locked password and the shell set to `nologin` so that user account can't be used for anything else like interactive sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systemd` runs as a privileged user `root` so it can switch to any user (UID) and group (GID) using [`setuid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) and [`setgid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setgid.2.html) calls.

A good practice is to create a separate user for a service with a locked password (`passwd -l user`, see [man passwd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html) for details), home set to the service working directory and the shell set to `nologin` so that user account can't be used for anything else like interactive sessions.

There are many additional options for tightening the security in the unit file itself, e.g. `ProtectSystem=`, `ProtectHome=`, `PrivateTmp=`, and `NoNewPrivileges=` see [man systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html).